# sqlite3 prepare statement not working, possibly improper pointers iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, sqlite

I have setup a GlobalVars class to hold my sqlite3 database variable.

```
static sqlite3** database;
const char *dbPath;


@implementation GlobalVars : NSObject

+(GlobalVars*)sharedInstance {
    static GlobalVars *myInstance = nil;
    if(myInstance == nil) {
        myInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }

    return myInstance;
}

+(sqlite3*)getGlobalDatabase {
    return &database;
}

+(void)setGlobalDatabase:(sqlite3*)_database {
    database = &_database;
}
```

Then in the header file I have

```
static sqlite3** database;
```

which is above the interface. This is how I setup my database variable.

I am then trying to access it when i open the database and prepare it. I can open it, because the open call returns true. I can not prepare it properly, because the statement returns false and it doesn't go into the if statement. I am wondering if I have messed up my pointers, because the prepare statement isn't working, and it doesn't prepare it properly.

```
-(void)setAllValues:(NSMutableArray*)array {
if(sqlite3_open([GlobalVars getGlobalDBPath], [GlobalVars getGlobalDatabase]) == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_stmt *insertStatement;
    NSString *sqlInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into my_table ('_id', 'name', 'age', 'weight', 'height', 'description') VALUES (%i, '%@', '%i', '%i', '%@', '%@')", ID, name, age, weight, height, description];

//*********** This is not opening, and SQLITE_OK is equal to false ***********

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(([GlobalVars getGlobalDatabase]), [sqlInsert UTF8String], -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if(sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"insert stepping done");
        }

        sqlite3_reset(insertStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement);
    sqlite3_close([GlobalVars getGlobalDatabase]);
}
}
```

The variables for the database are all filled with their correct data, and it seems to open the database without issues. When it comes to preparing, it does not work properly and returns false. Any ideas why. Thank you for your assistance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Log `sqlite3_errmsg` when the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails.

Comment: So, what does sqlite3_errmsg say?  And what is the return code that DOES come back from sqlite3_prepare_v2?

Comment: @HotLicks
The sqlite3_errmsg says "library routine called out of sequence"

Comment: Uh, the way you handle "GlobalDatabase" is broken.  Your indirection is all wrong, and, for certain, it should be different between open and prepare (which it isn't).

Comment: (I suspect you do not understand C language indirection.)

Comment: I have solved it, thank you for your guidance. It involved a deeper understanding of pointers to pointers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**

## You must try this one ... Maybe its help you :

**

```
    #import "DBManager.h"
#import "userRegistrationClass.h"

static DBManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;

@implementation DBManager


#pragma mark
#pragma mark Get shared Function
+(DBManager*)getSharedInstance{
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];
        [sharedInstance createDB];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark Create DataBase
-(BOOL)createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    // Get the documents directory
//    http://www.mycashkit.com/my-earnings.php
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"Dir Path Value is  %@",dirPaths);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"DocsDir Path Value is %@",docsDir);
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"UserRegInfo.sqlite"]];
    NSLog(@"Data base Work's %@:",databasePath);
    BOOL isSuccess = YES;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   // NSString *currentPath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
    NSLog(@"My file managaer value is %@",filemgr);
    //NSLog(@"My current drictory path is %@",currentPath);
    //the file will not be there when we load the application for the first time
    //so this will create the database table
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        NSLog(@"Constan charcter value is %s:-",dbpath);

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "create table if not exists UserInfo(UserID integer primary key, UserName,Gender,UserEmailID,Password,RePassword,DOB, MobileNo,IsUserType)";
            const char *sql_stmt2 = "create table if not exists TestInfo(TestID integer primary key, TestName,TestType)";

//            NSString *dbPathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserRegInfo.sqlite"];[filemgr copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

            NSLog(@"Constan charcter value is %s:-",dbpath);
            if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) && (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt2, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)!= SQLITE_OK))
            {
                isSuccess = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
            NSLog(@"Print Sqlite%d",(sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)));
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return  isSuccess;
        }
        else {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }

    }
    return isSuccess;
}
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Save Data Function

-(BOOL)saveData:(NSString*)insertSQL{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@" my Sqlite Query is :- %@",insertSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Squlite Error Msg is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. The `saveData` method open the database but doesn't close it. The `saveData` method prepares a statement but doesn't finalize it. The two calls to `sqlite3_exec` don't have proper error checking.

Comment: Working and correct are not always the same thing. You need to fix the issues or eventually you will have problems.